# Javascript function with vars on PHP print: quotes

Tags: php, javascript, function, quotes

I was just wondering if there is a better way to write down this PHP vars passed to a javascript function called inside a PHP print.:

```
while($nav = mysqli_fetch_array($nav_db)){
    print  '<li>
             <a href="#" onclick="getProductPage('.$nav['id'].', \''.$name.'\')">
                       '.$nav['Data'].'

             </a>
        </li>';
}
```

where

```
$nav['id']
```

is an INTEGER so I don't need extra '' for the JS, and

```
$name
```

is not an INTEGER so I need those \' \' for the JS.

Especially this step:

```
getProductPage('.$nav['id'].', \''.$name.'\')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php while($nav = mysqli_fetch_array($nav_db)): ?>
  <li>
     <a onclick="getProductPage(<?php echo $nav['id']; ?>, '<?php echo $name; ?>')">
        <?php echo $nav['Data']; ?>
     </a>
  </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You should break out of PHP to write html. It is cleaner this way. Also, you had a rogue `</span>` in there and no need for a `<br>` in a `<li>` menu.
Also, an `a` tag should have an `href` value in there, even if it is `#` or `javascript:void(0)` or something.

Comment: Thank you.. I thought at this option, but then I have all those <?php ?> inside the HTML, although I could use <?= ?>

Comment: having the php tags is just part of using php. you can use shorthand if you just don't want to type echo.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain me better, why should I never leave away the href on an a tag?

Comment: "never" may be extreme. Just that the anchor tag expects to be used as an anchor by href or name, so when it is just left without either of these it may be considered invalid. It will still work, but you might as well use a span tag if this is how you intend to write it.

Comment: `<?=` is equivalent to `<?php echo ` as a matter of fact Zend Framework 1.x's Stream Wrapper `Zend_View_Stream` literally does `str_replace("<?=", "<?php echo", $data);` to allow this type of short tag on hosts that don't natively support it (PHP < 5.2 with short_open_tags off)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to pass variables from php to javascript. That will make sure that there are no unescaped characters that can break your javascript.

So `json_encode($name)` instead of `$name`, etc.

For your example:

```
print  '<li>
         <a onclick="getProductPage(' . (int) $nav['id'].', ' . json_encode($name) . ')">
                   ' . htmlspecialchars($nav['Data']) . '

         </a>
    </li>';
```

Comment: Thank you, I learned about a new function today!
To be sure I'll use it in the right mode, can you write me the entire section starting from <a onclick...>?

Comment: Ok, thanks but now you are using json_encode also for a printed var (not passed to JS), and those \' \' still remain! Is it right?

Comment: @user2120569 Oops, you're right, that should have been `htmlspecialchars` instead. And without the additional quotes, it is already a js variable. For integers I prefer casting, but that's just me.

Comment: Thank you... unfortunately it isn't working! The javascript function is not called, is there anywhere a syntax error?
If I'm setting $link->set_charset('UTF8'); do I need to uso again htmlspecialchars?

Comment: @user2120569 Just look at the html source in the browser and use an html validator to make sure the html is okay. By the way, `htmlspecialchars` is to encode characters like `<` and `>` so that they don't ruin your html. You always need that when you output to html, regardless of the character set.

Comment: Perfect! From the HTML Validator:
Line 133, Column 47: an attribute value literal can occur in an attribute specification list only after a VI delimiter
<a href="#" onclick="getProductPage(5, "en)">
Have you forgotten the "equal" sign marking the separation between the attribute and its declared value? Typical syntax is attribute="value". Why is json_encode not appling the second " after en?

Comment: @user2120569 It does, the problem is that `json_encode` uses double quotes and you do the same for the `onclick` function. If you use single quotes for the `onclick` function, you should be able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using jquery and ajax send data to a php file and send back json_encode array to javascript?

example

after you send ajax call to php with datatype json, send back vars like this

```
$data['id'] = nav['id'];

echo json_encode($data);

or just $nav['id']

echo json_encode($nav)
```

in your javascript. on success, you can retrieve the id value like this

```
ajax{(
    blah,
    blah,
    ...
    success(msg){
    alert(msg.id)
    }
})
```

you can access the var as an object
the code above will alert the value of the id. you can assign msg.id to a javascript var or pass it to a function ...ect